# Why does datetime.datetime.utcnow() not contain timezone information?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

Why does this `datetime` not have any timezone info given that it is explicitly a UTC `datetime`?

I would expect that this would contain `tzinfo`.

Comment: How to convert a normal iso format date field which is of type string to utc format?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

That means it is timezone naive, so you can't use it with `datetime.astimezone`

you can give it a timezone like this

```
import pytz  # 3rd party: $ pip install pytz

u = datetime.utcnow()
u = u.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) #NOTE: it works only with a fixed utc offset
```

now you can change timezones

```
print(u.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/New_York")))
```

To get the current time in a given timezone, you could pass tzinfo to `datetime.now()` directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

print(datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York")))
```

It works for any timezone including those that observe daylight saving time (DST) i.e., it works for timezones that may have different utc offsets at different times (non-fixed utc offset). Don't use `tz.localize(datetime.now())` -- it may fail during end-of-DST transition when the local time is ambiguous.

Comment: But there's no good reason for it to be timezone naive - it's specified to be UTC. Why do you need to search out a third party library to make it work properly?

Comment: I think it may have been a licensing thing, so pytz can't be included in the stdlib

Comment: I agree; for me ‘naïve’ times are completely useless. There is discussion on the python list at the moment about adding pytz to the stdlib; the issue is not licensing but the fact that the timezone data is updated so often (which Python itself can't be). Also pytz doesn't implement the tzinfo interface in the expected way so you can get errors if you try to use some of the city timezones in `astimezone`. So datetime not only has no native timezones, but the only widely-available implementation of tzinfo is non-compliant to the supposed standard.

Comment: @bobince Why don't pytz and the standard datetime libraries work for you? The Python core and pytz evolving as independent projects reduces logistical complexity for the core team.  Yes, reducing the complexity for the Python core team increases the complexity for all of the Python users who need to deal with timezones but, I trust they made this decision for a good reason.  The rule "The standard library has no tzinfo instances..." is great because it's simple, why make an exception here?

Comment: How about just `u=datetime.now(pytz.utc)`

Comment: @bobince The lack of tzinfo in the standard library is surely a problem, but I don't see how writing your own code as a solution it's easier, faster, or better than using the pytz library which is the de-facto standard in the python world.

Comment: I use datetime/pytz in some projects (eg where interacting with Django), but I find it very inconvenient. You invariably end up with a mixture of naïve times, UTC times, local times, local DST times, and other-server-local-times (eg DB). The result is confusion and bugs. It was ultimately a mistake to try to shoehorn fundamentally different models (an abstract calendar point, an absolute universal moment, and a combination of both) into the same datatype. I much prefer dealing with only a timestamp for data, combined with regional formatting/parsing.

Comment: `tzinfo=` does not work with pytz for DST timezones, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171189/python-tz-am-i-wrong-or-its-a-bug#2171624).

Comment: @bain: don't use `tz.localize(datetime.now())`; use `datetime.now(tz)` instead.

Comment: @J.F Is that always correct? [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) "This library differs from the documented Python API for tzinfo implementations; if you want to create local wallclock times you need to use the localize() method documented in this document." - the docs do not make clear when it is safe to ignore that rule, perhaps it is always safe for datetime.now (?) but in general passing a pytz timezone to a datetime is risky e.g. `datetime(2015, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))`

Comment: @bain: `now(tz)` is always correct. We are not discussing anything else here.

Comment: If I have to guess why utcnow() does not include tzinfo, it's probably because of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). In other words, even UTC is subject to change. If utcnow() included a tzinfo, there are bound to be naïve programmers who don't realize that even the utc tzinfo needs to be updated from time to time, and then they run into time-related bugs and would still scratch their heads.

Comment: @J.F Author of pytz says `now(tz)` [is not always correct](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1319939/comments/12): 'even "datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Australia/Melbourne'))" could give you a timestamp out by one hour if you were unlucky and the DST transition occurred while that statement was being run.'

Comment: @bain: it just proves that even the pytz author can be wrong. I've seen the code. `now(tz)` that calls `tz.fromutc` internally works even during DST transitions (because there is no DST transitions in utc). If you think I'm wrong; provide specific example (date, timezone, python, pytz version)

Comment: A long time later from the original answer, but a relatively safe localize way built into pytz: `pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())`. I've found this also incorporates the DST variations without issue.

Comment: In 3.9+ python added the [ZoneInfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) class which can be used as `ZoneInfo('America/Denver')` and not use a 3rd party lib. Note that if the operating system doesn't have the zone files available it will fall back to `tzdata` from pypi (you'd need to install it). See [PEP615](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0615/)

Answer (score 358):

Note that for Python 3.2 onwards, the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module contains [`datetime.timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone). The documentation for [`datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) says:

> An aware current UTC datetime can be obtained by calling [`datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)`(`[`timezone.utc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone.utc)`)`.

So, `datetime.utcnow()` doesn't set `tzinfo` to indicate that it is UTC, but `datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` does return UTC time *with* `tzinfo` set.

So you can do:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 2, 43, 55, 230107, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Since Python 3.11, there also exists [`datetime.UTC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.UTC) which is equivalent to `datetime.timezone.utc`. So you can also do `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)`.

Comment: Which is prefered? `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` or `datetime.utcnow(timezone.utc)`?

Comment: `datetime.utcnow()` takes no arguments. So it would have to be `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Comment: `datetime.now()` will return the machine time but `datetime.utcnow()` will return the actual UTC time.

Comment: @Babu: `datetime.utcnow()` doesn't set `tzinfo` to indicate that it is UTC. But `datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` does return UTC time *with* `tzinfo` set.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen So if we pass a `tz` object in the now constructor it will return time of that timezone? Ok! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think this is the proper solution now, one shouldn't need to add an external dependency to specify the timezone metadata when it's already explicitly UTC

Comment: Never use `datetime.utcnow()`. It doesn't set `tzinfo` though it is utc,  but naive datetime object is presumed to represent system local time by datetime library. If your system local time is not UTC, `datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)` gives wrong result.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one

Comment: Didn't answer the question - why does it not contain timezone information?

Comment: @BB. the question is unanswerable as asked.  But this answers the question *behind* the question - how do you get a `datetime` object in UTC with the proper `tzinfo` attached?

Comment: Heads up, as of Python 3.12 [`datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) is deprecated in favor of `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Answer (score 88):

The standard Python libraries didn't include any tzinfo classes until Python 3.2. I can only guess at the reasons. Personally I think it was a mistake not to include a tzinfo class for UTC, because that one is uncontroversial enough to have a standard implementation.  Although there was no implementation in the library, there is one given as an example in the [`tzinfo` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects).

```
from datetime import timedelta, tzinfo

ZERO = timedelta(0)

# A UTC class.

class UTC(tzinfo):
    """UTC"""

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO

utc = UTC()
```

Once you have a UTC `tzinfo` object, you still can't use it with `utcnow`.  To get the current time as an aware datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime 

now = datetime.now(utc)
```

In Python 3.2 they finally put a UTC `tzinfo` class in the library:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone 

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

In Python 3.9 they created `tzinfo` classes for all the other time zones.  See [PEP 615 -- Support for the IANA Time Zone Database in the Standard Library](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0615/) for all the details.

Comment: Go figure as to why this class was not provided in the first place (and, more importantly, used for `datetime` objects created by `utcnow()`)...

Comment: @rgove, that's the kind of righting of wrongs that was supposed to be fair game for Python 3. They shouldn't have worried about the backward compatibility. There's another example I read within the last few days - the `struct` module would do automatic conversions from Unicode to bytestring, and the final decision was to break compatibility with earlier Python 3 versions to prevent a bad decision from going forward.

Comment: I'm dumbfounded that Python's `tzinfo` documentation includes examples of code to implement it, but they don't include that functionality in datetime itself!  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc

Comment: Also, the example UTC class shown here is almost exactly what the `pytz` module's implementation contains.  It adds a few helpful methods.

Comment: @LS yes, `pytz` is a great resource. By the time I had edited my answer to put in the example code, somebody else had already suggested it and I didn't want to steal their thunder.

Comment: This is the right answer. For backward compatibility, `utcnow()` is kept as it is.

Answer (score 21):

The `pytz` module is one option, and there is another `python-dateutil`, which although is also third party package, may already be available depending on your other dependencies and operating system.

I just wanted to include this methodology for reference- if you've already installed `python-dateutil` for other purposes, you can use its `tzinfo` instead of duplicating with `pytz`

```
import datetime
import dateutil.tz

# Get the UTC time with datetime.now:
utcdt = datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzutc())

# Get the UTC time with datetime.utcnow:
utcdt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utcdt = utcdt.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())

# For fun- get the local time
localdt = datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())
```

I tend to agree that calls to `utcnow` should include the UTC timezone information. I suspect that this is not included because the native datetime library defaults to naive datetimes for cross compatibility.

Comment: NameError: name 'dt' is not defined

Comment: I was using the datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp() call, and needing to add tzinfo, The second solution worked for me:

`utcdt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1234567890).replace(dateutil.tz.tzutc())`

Comment: note: unlike `datetime.now(pytz_tz)` that always works; [`datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())` may fail during DST transitions](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/57). [PEP 495 -- Local Time Disambiguation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0495/) might improve `dateutil` situation in the future.

Comment: @IanLee: you could use `utc_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1234567890, dateutil.tz.tzutc())` (note: [`dateutil` with a non-fixed utc offset (such as `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()`) may fail here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17365806/4279), use [a `pytz`-based solution instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12692910/4279)).

Comment: Since my program was already importing `dateutil` for `dateutil.parser`, I liked this solution best.  It was as simple as: `utcCurrentTime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=dateutil.tz.tzutc())`. Viola!!

Comment: Thanks, @IanLee. The part that still puzzles me is that a method called utcfromtimestamp, which takes a POSIX timestamp as a parameter, which by definition is UTC, still produces a naïve datetime. It seems like a plain oversight to me.

Answer (score 16):

To add `timezone` information in Python 3.2+

```
import datetime

>>> d = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> print(d.tzinfo)
'UTC+00:00'
```

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timezone'
```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)

Comment: @MarcinOwsiany try: `from datetime import datetime, timezone` then invoke with `datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)`

Comment: This is the best way to get UTC timezone aware datetime object without using any third party python module like **pytz**. | Just to add one more thing. If you want to get LOCAL timezone aware datetime object without using any extra module then just add astimezone(): **d.astimezone()**

Answer (score 11):

Julien Danjou wrote a good article explaining [why you should never deal with timezones](http://web.archive.org/web/20201108141932/https://julien.danjou.info/python-and-timezones). An excerpt:

> Indeed, Python datetime API always returns unaware datetime objects,
> which is very unfortunate. Indeed, as soon as you get one of this
> object, there is no way to know what the timezone is, therefore these
> objects are pretty "useless" on their own.

Alas, even though you may use `utcnow()`, you still won't see the timezone info, as you discovered.

Recommendations:

> - Always use aware `datetime` objects, i.e. with timezone information. That
>   makes sure you can compare them directly (aware and unaware `datetime`
>   objects are not comparable) and will return them correctly to users.
>   Leverage **pytz** to have timezone objects.
> - Use **ISO 8601** as the input and
>   output string format. Use `datetime.datetime.isoformat()` to return
>   timestamps as string formatted using that format, which includes the
>   timezone information.
> - If you need to parse strings containing ISO 8601 formatted timestamps,
>   you can rely on `iso8601`, which returns timestamps with correct
>   timezone information. This makes timestamps directly comparable.

Comment: This is slightly misleading recommendation. The rule of thumb is, never deal with timezones. Always store and transmit tz unware utc objects (epoch objects). Timezone should be only calculated at the time of representation in UI

Comment: That sounds like it already matches up with Julien's thoughts quite well. Which of his specific recommendations (as referenced above) are misleading?

Comment: TZ unaware objects are not a problem if all datetime math is done in UTC. You should store and process all datetime in UTC and only convert datetime value to a specific TZ for a human when requested (i.e. at the UI layer).

Comment: I think why @nehem called it misleading is more due to Julien's phrasing of "never deal with," since colloquially that's often used/interpreted as "ignore." Yet the essence of his recommendations is the opposite—that you in fact _always_ need time zones on timestamps so you can normalize/store/compare accurately. So you still have to "deal with" them, just long enough to work out the UTC equivalent—and to Tom Scott's points, leaving the ugly _mechanics_ of timezone conversions to things that already do that well instead of reinventing square wheels.

Comment: @BrianCline Do people still use stackoverflow ? ‍♂️

Comment: @nehem Yes, millions. A bit off topic for this question.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` returning UTC time as naive datetime object is obviously problematic and must be fixed. It can lead to unexpected result if your system local timezone is not UTC, since datetime library presume naive datetime object to represent system local time. For example, `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestaamp()` gives timestamp of 4 hours ahead from correct value on my computer. Also, as of python 3.6, `datetime.astimezone()` can be called on naive datetime instances, but `datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone(any_timezone)` gives wrong result unless your system local timezone is UTC.

Comment: those of us using `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` since it was ever introduced into Python aren't using tz-aware objects in most cases anyway - we're only ever storing and processing UTC and only doing the conversion for human users at the UI level. If you want UTC with tzinfo for some reason, only stick to the modern datetime objects that have tz support.

Answer (score 3):

It should include and `now()` also. Related [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88829).

So till that, `now()` is preferred over `today()` and `utcnow()`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
utc = timezone.utc
date = datetime.now(utc)
print(date) # 2022-04-06 05:40:13.025347+00:00
```

Comment: Simplest and most accurate method today. The reason:
`date = datetime.now(timezone.utc) # datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 13, 8, 17, 21, 862183, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` and `date = datetime.utcnow() #datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 13, 8, 17, 35, 668704)`

Answer (score -7):

```
from datetime import datetime 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
d = datetime.now()
date = datetime.isoformat(d).split('.')[0]
d_month = datetime.today() + relativedelta(months=1)
next_month = datetime.isoformat(d_month).split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score -16):

UTC dates don't need any timezone info since they're UTC, which by definition means that they have no offset.

Comment: As far as I can tell from http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html, a datetime without a tzinfo is one where the time zone is unspecified. Here the time zone *has* been specified, so logically it should be present. There's a big difference between a date/time without an associated time zone and one which is definitely in UTC. (Ideally they should be different types IMO, but that's another matter...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you're missing Ignacio's point that UTC isn't a timezone.  Amazing that this answer has -9 score as I type this...

Comment: @CS: Well Ignacio never stated that... and while strictly speaking UTC isn't a time zone, it's usually *treated* as one to make lives considerably simpler (including in Python, e.g. with `pytz.utc`). Note that there's a big difference between a value whose offset from UTC is unknown and one where it is known to be 0. The latter is what `utcnow()` *should* return, IMO. That would fit in with "An aware object is used to represent a specific moment in time that is not open to interpretation" as per the documentation.