# In Python, how do you convert seconds since epoch to a `datetime` object?

Tags: python, datetime, date, time, epoch

The `time` module can be initialized using seconds since epoch:

```py
import time
t1 = time.gmtime(1284286794)
t1
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=10, tm_min=19, 
                 tm_sec=54, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=255, tm_isdst=0)
```

Is there an elegant way to initialize a `datetime.datetime` object in the same way?

Comment: for the opposite operation go here: [convert-a-datetime-object-to-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/in-python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-object-to-seconds)

Answer (score 548, accepted):

[`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) will do, if you know the time zone, you could produce the same output as with `time.gmtime`

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1284286794)
datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 12, 11, 19, 54)
```

or

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1284286794)
datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 12, 10, 19, 54)
```

Comment: bizarrely, `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` creates a naive timestamp.  I had to `import pytz` and use `datetime.fromtimestamp(1423524051, pytz.utc)` to create an aware datetime.

Comment: as a follow-on to the above, with Python >= 3.2 you don't have to import the `pytz` library if you only want the UTC timestamp - you only need to `from datetime import datetime, timezone` and then call it as follows: `datetime.fromtimestamp(1423524051, timezone.utc)`. It has saved the extra library many times when I only need the UTC timezone from `pytz`.

Answer (score 62):

Seconds since epoch to [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) to [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> ts_epoch = 1362301382
>>> ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_epoch).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> ts
'2013-03-03 01:03:02'
```

Comment: It should be datetime.fromtimestamp(1579366345).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: @vml19, it depends on whether `datetime` was imported from `datetime` or not (`import datetime` vs. `from datetime import datetime`).

Answer (score 53):

From the docs, the recommended way of getting a timezone aware datetime object from seconds since epoch is:

[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, timezone.utc)
```

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), using [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.utc)
```

Comment: A link to the documentation in your subtitles ("Python 3", "Python 2") would be useful - and I also recommend changing their order.

Comment: Updated. Leaving the order the same, since that matches the Python docs.

Comment: you don't need `pytz` just to get `utc` tzinfo object. [It is easy to create it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2331635/4279)

Answer (score 10):

Note that datetime.datetime.[fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)(timestamp) and .[utcfromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)(timestamp) fail on windows for dates before Jan. 1, 1970 while negative unix timestamps seem to work on unix-based platforms. The docs say this:

> "[This may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out of the range of
>   values supported by the platform C gmtime() function. It’s common for
>   this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)"

See also [Issue1646728](http://bugs.python.org/issue1646728)

Comment: :o) yes, still some 23 years to let it get fixed

Comment: you could use `utc_time = datetime(1970,1,1) + timedelta(seconds=timestamp)`, to workaround it.

Comment: This is a problem. There are many people who are born before 1970 or Dec 31 1969 in the US! Those DOBs stored in Java may break intraoperatively then.

Answer (score 7):

For those that want it ISO 8601 compliant, since the other solutions do not have the `T` separator nor the time offset (except **Meistro**'s answer):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(1463288494, timezone.utc).isoformat('T', 'microseconds')
print(result) # 2016-05-15T05:01:34.000000+00:00
```

Note, I use `fromtimestamp` because if I used `utcfromtimestamp` I would need to chain on `.astimezone(...)` anyway to get the offset.

If you don't want to go all the way to `microseconds` you can choose a different unit with the
[isoformat()](https://pythontic.com/datetime/datetime/isoformat) method.