# Python Pandas Series of Datetimes to Seconds Since the Epoch

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Following in the spirit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds), I attempted the following to convert a DataFrame column of datetimes to a column of seconds since the epoch.

```
df['date'] = (df['date']+datetime.timedelta(hours=2)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1))
df['date'].map(lambda td:td.total_seconds())
```

The second command causes the following error which I do not understand. Any thoughts on what might be going on here? I replaced map with apply and that didn't help matters.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-7123e823f995> in <module>()
----> 1 df['date'].map(lambda td:td.total_seconds())

/Users/cpd/.virtualenvs/py27-ipython+pandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0_937_gb55c790-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/series.pyc in map(self, arg, na_action)
   1932             return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   1933         else:
-> 1934             mapped = map_f(values, arg)
   1935             return self._constructor(mapped, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   1936 

/Users/cpd/.virtualenvs/py27-ipython+pandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0_937_gb55c790-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:43628)()

<ipython-input-99-7123e823f995> in <lambda>(td)
----> 1 df['date'].map(lambda td:td.total_seconds())

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Comment: It seems the 'date' column may not be a datetime64 in the first place?

Comment: Does the column contain any missing values?  Missing values usually cause pandas Series to be cast to floats, causing weirdness when you try to interpret them as datetimes.

Comment: @Abe Indeed you were right. Turns out there is some missing data in some of the records. Not what I anticipated... Ack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update:

In 0.15.0 `Timedeltas` became a full-fledged dtype.

So this becomes possible (as well as the methods below)

```
In [45]: s = Series(pd.timedelta_range('1 day',freq='1S',periods=5))                         

In [46]: s.dt.components
Out[46]: 
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0     1      0        0        0             0             0            0
1     1      0        0        1             0             0            0
2     1      0        0        2             0             0            0
3     1      0        0        3             0             0            0
4     1      0        0        4             0             0            0

In [47]: s.astype('timedelta64[s]')
Out[47]: 
0    86400
1    86401
2    86402
3    86403
4    86404
dtype: float64
```

Original Answer:

I see that you are on master (and 0.13 is coming out very shortly), 
so assuming you have numpy >= 1.7. Do this. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas-reductions) for the docs (this is frequency conversion)

```
In [5]: df = DataFrame(dict(date = date_range('20130101',periods=10)))

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
                 date
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2 2013-01-03 00:00:00
3 2013-01-04 00:00:00
4 2013-01-05 00:00:00
5 2013-01-06 00:00:00
6 2013-01-07 00:00:00
7 2013-01-08 00:00:00
8 2013-01-09 00:00:00
9 2013-01-10 00:00:00

In [7]: df['date']+timedelta(hours=2)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
Out[7]: 
0   15706 days, 02:00:00
1   15707 days, 02:00:00
2   15708 days, 02:00:00
3   15709 days, 02:00:00
4   15710 days, 02:00:00
5   15711 days, 02:00:00
6   15712 days, 02:00:00
7   15713 days, 02:00:00
8   15714 days, 02:00:00
9   15715 days, 02:00:00
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [9]: (df['date']+timedelta(hours=2)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)) / np.timedelta64(1,'s')
Out[9]: 
0    1357005600
1    1357092000
2    1357178400
3    1357264800
4    1357351200
5    1357437600
6    1357524000
7    1357610400
8    1357696800
9    1357783200
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

The contained values are `np.timedelta64[ns]` objects, they don't have the same methods as `timedelta` objects, so no `total_seconds()`.

```
In [10]: s = (df['date']+timedelta(hours=2)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1))

In [11]: s[0]
Out[11]: numpy.timedelta64(1357005600000000000,'ns')
```

You can astype them to int, and you get back a `ns` unit.

```
In [12]: s[0].astype(int)
Out[12]: 1357005600000000000
```

You can do this as well (but only on an individual unit element).

```
In [18]: s[0].astype('timedelta64[s]')
Out[18]: numpy.timedelta64(1357005600,'s')
```

Comment: Perfect Jeff, thank you! Once I got rid of the rows with missing data, I could directly apply this to the new problem. ;-)

Comment: you don't need to remove missing values (NaT); they will be returned as nan

Comment: I don't have time right now to edit (and re-verify) the answer, but in fact version 0.13 now allows 'astype' operations to be applied to an entire Series. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions, or  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html and do a find-on-page for 'astype'.

Comment: I'm searching for a method to convert `Series` of `Timedelta`s to `seconds` for plotting. Your approach with `/ pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)` is a nice one. Stiil, I wonder if there is a better method. What do you think?

Comment: this answer actually is pretty outdated; Timedeltas became fully fledged types in 0.15.0. I will add another method.

Answer (score 1):

Since recent versions of Pandas, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe from 2023-05-06 to 2023-06-04
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2023-05-26', periods=10, freq='D')})

df['timestamp'] = (df['date'].add(pd.DateOffset(hours=2))  # add hour offset
                             .sub(pd.Timestamp(0))  # subtract 1970-1-1
                             .dt.total_seconds()  # extract total of seconds
                             .astype(int))  # downcast float64 to int64
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        date   timestamp
0 2023-05-26  1685066400
1 2023-05-27  1685152800
2 2023-05-28  1685239200
3 2023-05-29  1685325600
4 2023-05-30  1685412000
5 2023-05-31  1685498400
6 2023-06-01  1685584800
7 2023-06-02  1685671200
8 2023-06-03  1685757600
9 2023-06-04  1685844000
```

The key is to subtract the origin (`pd.Timestamp(0)`) to each dates (`DatetimeIndex`) then use the `dt` accessor to extract from the result (`TimedeltaIndex`) the number of seconds. You can also downcast the numeric result (`float64` to `int64`).