# pandas dataframe column value to unix-like timestamp value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

my question is simple. How do I convert pandas column value to unix-like timestamp?

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time']) 
print(data['time']) 

# output 
0   2016-05-04 18:38:32.076
1   2016-05-04 18:39:15.556
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]  


my desired result: 
0    1238475858
1    1238475859
```

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553464/python-pandas-series-of-datetimes-to-seconds-since-the-epoch

Comment: Do you think  `df['time'] = df['time'].values.astype(np.int64)` ?

Comment: Small correction to @jezrael's comment: `df['unix_ts'] = df['time'].astype(np.int64)//10**9`

Comment: @MaxU - Yes, question is if need `ns` or `s` ;)

Comment: @jezrael, [number of __seconds__ that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) ;-)

Comment: ok, then you are right.

Comment: You can you 'dt' attribute to access datetime methods, such as timestamp(). So to answer your question is should be doable with data['time'].dt.timestamp()