# How to test the date of a changeset in Mercurial API

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-api

I want to use the Mercurial Python API on only changesets that fall within a certain range, and from reading the [docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi), I haven't been able to work out how to do it.

My code looks like this:

```
from mercurial import ui, hg
import datetime

repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), 'path_to_repo' )

start_date = datetime.datetime( 1997,  01, 01 )
end_date   = datetime.datetime( 2000,  12, 31 )

# Print every changesetid in required range
for changesetid in repo:
    #print repo[changesetid]
    changeset = repo.changectx( changesetid )
    date = changeset.date()[0]
    if ( date > start_date and date < end_date):
        # Do stuff...
        pass
```

And the output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    if ( date > start_date and date < end_date):
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to float
```

Example output dates are:

- 645630248.0
- 887802818.0

I've also seen ['hg help dates'](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#date-formats), but can't tell from this how to convert from a day/month/year date to Mercurial's internal representation.

How do I convert my cutoff dates to a numeric format that is suitable for comparison the date value returned by changectx.date(), please?

---

*PS I know that for an example this trivial, there are better ways of doing this using the hg command directly... what I haven't included in my example code is the complex steps I wish to add at the "Do stuff" point!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, please remember that **the internal Mercurial API is not stable**.  You should seriously consider using Mercurial's command-line directly if at all possible.  Remember that there are XML templates (by passing `--style=xml`) if you find parsing the default output too annoying.

That said, this is most easily done with revsets, just as you would do at the command line:

```py
from mercurial import ui, hg
repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), '/some/path/to/repo')
changesets = repo.revs("date('>1999-01-01') and date('<2000-12-31')")
```

As a bonus, this will go through Mercurial's internal revset optimizer.

Comment: Thank you - that answers the question, and I learned of the JSON templates too.

Comment: No problem.  I also realized that the templates that are actually shipping right now are XML, not JSON.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working in the end, and put the functionality into the `python_internal_date()` helper function below:

```
from mercurial import ui, hg
import datetime, time

repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), 'path_to_repo' )

def python_internal_date( year, month, day ):
    # From http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852891/104370
    start_date = datetime.datetime( year,  month, day )
    return time.mktime( start_date.timetuple() )

start_date = python_internal_date( 1997, 01, 01 )
end_date   = python_internal_date( 2000, 12, 31 )

# Print every changesetid in required range
for changesetid in repo:
    #print repo[changesetid]
    changeset = repo.changectx( changesetid )
    date = changeset.date()[0]
    if ( date > start_date and date < end_date):
        # Do stuff...
        pass
```