# how to convert format of date to 'os.utime()' format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert an ordinal dateTime value into a value that can be accepted by os.utime()

My date has the format: 201642322295

(which is: year=2016, month=4, day=23, hour=22, minute=29, second=5)

However, the method won't accept this and I'm not sure how to/ what to convert it into. I've tried converting it into a datetime also but this does not work.

The code segment:

```
s = int(self.newTime)
date = datetime(year=s[0:4], month=s[4], day=s[5:2], hour=s[8:2], minute=s[10:2], second=s[12])
os.utime(self.fileName, (date,date))
```

(I had tried using just the ordinal format, which modifies the datetime of the file but is not at all correct)

**edit:** This is not the same as 'python converting datetime to be used in os.utime' because it's using a completely different format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.utime` expects values in the form of integers representing a untix timestamp.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24182696/1810460)

```
s = int(self.newTime)
date = datetime(year=s[0:4], month=s[4], day=s[5:2], hour=s[8:2], minute=s[10:2], second=s[12])
utime = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
os.utime(self.fileName, (utime, utime))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little closer but now I have a typeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: well, you're casting `self.newTime` to an `int` and then trying to get substrings out of it to create your datetime. That's definitely incorrect.

Comment: what is `self.newTime`?

Comment: it was originally a string: 'datetime.datetime2016 4 23 22 29 5' , that I took out of a database query, and then I cut that down to just '201642322295'

Comment: Oh right, of course! I was changing the code around so much I'd forgotten I changed it to an int

Comment: a pretty standard development hiccup. :) is everything working now?

Comment: yep, working like a beauty!