# convert elastic search timestamp attribute to seconds

Tags: python, elasticsearch, timestamp

How can i convert this timestamp value to an integer representing seconds-since-the-epoch in python

```
 2016-08-06T06:07:36.349Z
```

This is the timestamp value i received in elastic search query.

I tried searching but the timestamp format was different from this and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds) didn't helped neither any other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use python inbuilt datetime package and its strptime method to convert string into datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2016-08-06T06:07:36.349Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

after that you should get epoch datetime object which you can get by

```
epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
```

your final seconds can be derived from this method

```
def unix_time_millis(datetime):
    return (datetime - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0
```

so your complete code looks like

```
from datetime import datetime

epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

def unix_time_millis(datetime):
    return (datetime - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0

current_date = datetime.strptime("2016-08-06T06:07:36.349Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print unix_time_millis(current_date)
```

This answer is inspired from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111177/4453633

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Kumar

Comment: @sumit how can we convert the timestamp into general timestamp

Comment: @ak3191 I didn't understand your question, what is a timestamp vs. general timestamp? Could you please elaborate

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is an ES version discrepancy, but the date-time strings returned on `v2.4.6` don't have the trailing "Z". Also, in case `dt.microsecond == 0`, `str(dt)` will omit the `.000000` suffix, whereas `dt.strftime(fmt + ".%f")` will print it. So, depending on how the strings were generated in the first place, `strptime()` may raise a ValueError for nil microseconds. Is there an official ISO name for the date strings returned by ES? Also, your `datetime` local shadows the imported symbol.