# Get timestamp in seconds from python's datetime

Tags: python, timestamp

How to get timestamp from the structure datetime? What is right alternative for non-existing `datetime.utcnow().timestamp()`?

Comment: This answer below is much simpler than the accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56689007/3559330

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import time,datetime
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.today().timetuple())
```

Comment: Very cumbersome solution. As python. Many operations for such small work. C has time() and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 63):

use `time`, and `int` to remove the milliseconds

```
from time import time 

int(time())

# 1561043225
```

Answer (score 10):

There is another stupid trick - achieve `timedelta`

```
(datetime.utcnow()-datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)).total_seconds()
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852969/3743145). **Better**

```
(datetime.utcnow()-datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
```

And this solution contains subseconds.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have to get timestamp from structure datetime,  you can decrease instruction like this

```
import time
print time.time()
```

Comment: This construction returns the time in seconds since the epoch as a **floating point number**, for example: `1558442772.1057804`.

Answer (score -3):

If I understand correctly what sort of output you are seeking:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(timestamp)

> 11:44:40
```

EDIT: Appears I misinterpreted your question? You are asking for the naive universal time, then galaxyan's answer is concise.