# Python,os.path.getmtime(fullname) sb close to time.mktime(t.timetuple()) but isn't

Tags: python-2.7, time, os.path

I edited and saved a text file, "fullname" on my Windows 7 computer.
I ran the following two lines of code immediately after saving the edits to "fullname", and I expected both of the following lines of code to return almost the same number of seconds since the epoch:

```
print str(os.path.getmtime(fullname))
print str(time.mktime(t.timetuple()))
```

The second line of code was borrowed from [How to convert a Python datetime object to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds)

The results were not even close:

"1494082110.0"

"1319180400.0"

I would like to know why the results were not close.

My ultimate goal is that I want to know how to generate a float date, matching a calendar date of my choosing, 
for use in the context of:
    win32file.SetFileTime(handle, CreatedTime , AccessTime , WrittenTime )

Any help in understanding these issues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the *current* time with the time at which you saved the file. In this code I save a file, then I get the current time in `t` and display it, then I get the modification time for the file and display that. You may note that the two times differ by less than a half a second.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> import os
>>> fullname = 'temp.txt'
>>> open('temp.txt', 'w').write('something')
9
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> time.mktime(t.timetuple())
1502039202.0
>>> os.path.getmtime(fullname)
1502039187.4629886
```

I notice too that,

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1319180400)
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 21, 3, 0)
```

In other words, that second number in your question yields a date that came *before* you put your question.