# Storing datetime in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, numpy

Let's say I want to store datetime values over 100 iterations of a for loop in a numpy array like so:

```
import numpy as np
import time 
from datetime import datetime

Startmult = np.zeros((1,100))
for i in range(100): 
    Startmult[i] = datetime.now()
```

Whenever I do this, I get the following error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

Is there a way to overcome this error?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Also, now I would like to do the following, but can't seem to find a solution:

```
 CPUtime = np.zeros((100), dtype='datetime64[s]')
 for i in range(100): 
     Start = datetime.now() 
     CPUtime[i] = datetime.now()-Start
```

In now get the following error:

```
Could not convert object to NumPy datetime
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in the error message, we need to use a compatible dtype there, `float` won't do. One of the compatible ones would be `datetime64` and with it we need to specify the precision as well. Let's say we want for `seconds`. Then, the array initialization part would be -

```
Startmult = np.zeros((100), dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

All available time units are listed [`here`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units).

Here's a sample run for `nano-sec` run on `100` elements case and verifying with the first and last output elements -

```
In [447]: Startmult = np.zeros((100), dtype='datetime64[ns]')
     ...: for i in range(100): 
     ...:     Startmult[i] = datetime.now()
     ...:     

In [448]: Startmult[0] # first element
Out[448]: numpy.datetime64('2017-08-31T22:39:45.722306000')

In [449]: Startmult[-1] # last element
Out[449]: numpy.datetime64('2017-08-31T22:39:45.723201000')
```

---

Edit : If you are trying to store the seconds elapsed between two points in time as floating pt numbers, you could do something like this -

```
CPUtime = np.zeros((100))
for i in range(100): 
    Start = datetime.now()
    time_diff = datetime.now()-Start
    CPUtime[i] = time_diff.total_seconds()
```

For `u-sec` precision, use : `time_diff.microseconds`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I also have another question that you may be able to help me with (I've edited my original post).

Comment: @tattybojangler Check out Edit section please.

Answer (score 2):

your need to convert current datetime in integer format (only seconds)