# Python get total seconds from datetime results in occasional mistakes

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to follow [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds) and get the elapsed seconds since Jan 1st 1970 for each element in my array (`my_times`).  I'm then using these values to find the time intervals between each consecutive time.  Either approach I take seems to give the wrong answer for at least one pair of times.

### Mark Byers answer

To get the seconds since Jan 1st 1970, he suggested to try:

```
time.mktime(my_time.timetuple())
```

However this does not seem to work for times `"2017-11-05 01:46:00+00"` and `"2017-11-05 01:47:00+00"`.

When I run the below code, it says the values are separated by 3660.0 seconds instead of 60.0 seconds

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

my_time1 = datetime.strptime("2017-11-05 01:46:00+00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f")
my_time2 = datetime.strptime("2017-11-05 01:47:00+00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f")
time.mktime(my_time2.timetuple()) - time.mktime(my_time1.timetuple())
```

### Andrzej Pronobis' answer

To get the seconds since Jan 1st 1970, he suggested to try:

`my_time.timestamp()`

This fixed the two earlier times however it no longer works for times `"2017-11-05 01:59:00+00"` and `"2017-11-05 02:00:00+00"`.  The same issue appears, I get 3660.0 seconds instead of 60.0 seconds

```
from datetime import datetime

my_time1 = datetime.strptime("2017-11-05 01:59:00+00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f")
my_time2 = datetime.strptime("2017-11-05 02:00:00+00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f")
my_time2.timestamp() - my_time1.timestamp()
```

---

I'd like to know if I'm doing anything wrong?  Also is there a better way to find all consecutive time intervals when the datetime is given as a String?

---

### Edit:

Thank you John, that fixed the problem.  Oddly, changing the format from `+%f` to `%z` still ran into the same issue.

What did work was running `sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime` (changes my computer's time to UTC) and then evaluating all the times

Comment: Your code works for me and it seems strange that 01:46 and 01:47 should differ. If you just need the difference between two datetime objs you could use: (my_time2 - my_time1).total_seconds()

Comment: The error of 3600 seconds is equal to 1 hour (60*60 seconds). This is most likely an issue to do with daylight savings time. Convert your times to UTC and then subtract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of "garbage in, garbage out."  Here:

```
datetime.strptime("2017-11-05 01:59:00+00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f")
```

You probably think that `+00` on the end means "UTC time", but the %f format specifier means "fractional seconds."

In any case, you're apparently running on a system where the time zone is set to one with daylight saving time part of the year.  2 AM happens twice on the DST changeover date in November, so your code is working as written (it's ambiguous, basically).

Put another way: your issue is not that you're computing time deltas incorrectly.  Your issue is that you are loading the times from strings incorrectly (or ambiguously).