# How do I get seconds since 1/1/1970 of a Python datetime object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, seconds

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I wanted to get the number of seconds (or milliseconds) since 1/1/1970 for a datetime object.  Following the advice here -- [In Python, how do you convert a `datetime` object to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/in-python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-object-to-seconds), I implemented

```
now = datetime.now()
...
return [len(removed_elts) == 0, score, now.total_seconds()]
```

but the "now.total_seconds()" line is giving the error

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

What's the right way to get the seconds since 1/1/1970?

Comment: I think you are only having a problem because you didn't subtract the `datetime` objects to get a `timedelta` object (which does have an attribute `total_seconds`). I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852969/5982697) on the question you linked does what you want. But you can also use [`datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) as mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
now = datetime.now()
...
return [len(removed_elts) == 0, score, now.timestamp()]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
import datetime
first_date = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
time_since = datetime.datetime.now() - first_date
seconds = int(time_since.total_seconds())
```

Comment: Are "time_since" and "first_date" different object types?

Comment: they're bot `datetime` objects. @Dave

Comment: no it doesn't "01" isn't recognized by the interpreter should be:  datetime(1970, 1, 1) instead

Comment: You're correct, I've edited my answer. But after editing the answer, they do return datetime objects, and that was his question. @KoKlA

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
print(time.time())
```

Output:

```
1567532027.192546
```

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to the advice you mentioned, you don't call `total_seconds()` on a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object but on a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, which simply doesn't have this attribute.

So, one solution for Python 3.7 (and 2.7) could for example be:

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.now()
then = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
...
return [len(removed_elts) == 0, score, (now - then).total_seconds()]
```

Another shorter but less clear (at least on first sight) solution for Python 3.3+ (credits to [ababak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116545/ababak) for this one):

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.now()
...
return [len(removed_elts) == 0, score, now.timestamp()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = (now - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1))
print(delta.total_seconds())
```

`now` is of type `datetime.datetime` and has no `.total_seconds()` method.

`delta` is of type `datetime.timedelta` and does have a `.total_seconds()` method.

Hope this helps.