# find how much time is passed (datatime) between two rows

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

```
Subject.iloc[1, 0]  is equal to 

datetime.time(13, 16, 14, 336000)
```

and

```
Subject.iloc[2, 0]  is equal to 

datetime.time(13, 16, 14, 338000)
```

All I want to do is find the passed time from Subject.iloc[1, 0] to Subject.iloc[2, 0]
. But when I subtract them it would say

```
Subject.iloc[1, 0]-Subject.iloc[2, 0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

But then I thought maybe I should use time delta

```
  pd.to_timedelta(Subject.iloc[2, 0].astype(str))
```

which says 
       AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'astype'

Can anyone help me with this? What I am doing wrong?

Even this

```
pd.to_timedelta(Subject.iloc[2, 0]) won't work
```

Comment: Whats the error for this? `pd.to_timedelta(Subject.iloc[2, 0])`

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(str(Subject.iloc[2, 0]))`?

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan YES!!!! Thanks! Please answer in the answer section so I can confirm that my problem is solved. Thanks Henry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this

```py
d1 = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), Subject.iloc[2, 0])
d2 = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), Subject.iloc[1, 0])
diff = d1 - d2
```

To use the Pandas' `to_timedelta`, do as follows

```py
pd.to_timedelta(str(Subject.iloc[2, 0]))
```

Comment: How can I do it for the whole column?
pd.to_timedelta(str(Subject['TIme'))?
That won't work. DO you have anything in your mind?

Comment: will this help? https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-calculate-a-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-python

Comment: Actually I want to find the difference between Subject.iloc[0, 0] with all other rows. As in Subject.iloc[2, 0]-Subject.iloc[0, 0], Subject.iloc[3, 0]-Subject.iloc[0, 0] and so fourth.

Comment: @NavidRashedi idk much of Pandas, but I guess you need to iterate over all rows and subtract the fixed value of `Subject.iloc[0, 0]` then

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this recently for work actually. You can convert datetime (or a time struct object in my case) to "seconds since epoch" and then compare them.

[In Python, how do you convert a `datetime` object to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/in-python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-object-to-seconds)

For me it was more complicated:

```
durSec = time.mktime(time.strptime(data[7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) - time.mktime(time.strptime(data[6], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```