# How to get seconds time using strptime from a list

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I need to convert a list in seconds in Python. The list is the following:

[27.0, 2.0, 2019.0, 19.0, 59.0, 59.99]

That are day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds.

I tried to use datetime.strptime after converting it in a string, but it returns the error ValueError: time data '...' does not match format...

Comment: Show the desired result and your code.

Comment: The title is missleading; this has nothing to do with `strptime`. It should be something like "how to create a datetime object from a list". How to get seconds since the epoch can be found e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/in-python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-object-to-seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Using datetime but parsing the fields

Fields must be int (so convert from float)

```
from datetime import datetime

d = [27.0, 2.0, 2019.0, 19.0, 59.0, 59.99]

date = datetime(year = int(d[2]), month = int(d[1]), day=int(d[0]),
             hour = int(d[3]), minute = int(d[4]), second=int(d[5]),
             microsecond= int(1e6*(d[5]-int(d[5]))))

print(date)
# Output: 2019-02-27 19:59:59.990000

print((date-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()) # Seconds since Jan 1, 1970
                                                 # i.e. Unix time in seconds
# Output: 1551297599.99
```

Comment: It doesn't return the milliseconds :( and then how can I translate the date into seconds?

Comment: @Kitama--added a translation to seconds since Jan 1, 1970 (i.e. Unix time seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can try datetime package in python as below

```
import datetime
l = [27.0, 2.0, 2019.0, 19.0, 59.0, 59.99]
l_int = list(map(int,l))

d = datetime.datetime(l_int[2],l_int[1],l_int[0], l_int[3], l_int[4],l_int[5])
print(d)

#2019-02-27 19:59:59
```

Comment: in your list have you don't have microseconds

Comment: take a look at `59.99` - the `.99` are fractions of a second which you have to turn into mircroseconds, see @DarryIG 's answer.