# I am Not able to convert the unix time to local date and time in PYTHON

Tags: python

I wanted to convert the UNIX time into local date and time. I am getting the UNIX timestamp value from my server but when I convert the UNIX using these set of code I get a time which is 1 hour 30 min less than the actual time. But when I take the raw timestamp data and check in the online UNIX to local date and time converter I get the correct time.

```
import datetime

time_local = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1502705627085/1e3)
print time_local
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by the division?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize a datetime object with seconds since epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694487/initialize-a-datetime-object-with-seconds-since-epoch)

Comment: Check the timezones of your OS vs Python's

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import datetime
import tzlocal

time_local = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1502705627085/1e3, tzlocal.get_localzone())
print time_local
```

Answer (score 1):

is your timezone correct on your system ?

From the [python datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) :

> classmethod **datetime**.**fromtimestamp**(timestamp[, tz])
>
> Return the *local date and time* corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time(). If optional argument tz is None or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the *platform’s local date and time*, and the returned datetime object is naive.

If you cannot change your system's timezone, you can specify a tz as explained in the datetime module documentation.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but aren't timezones always in full hours, so how can it be 90 minutes off!? Just wondering if it may be some other problem.

Comment: Some timezone appears to have 30 min offsets like india tz compared to UTC (UTC+05:30). Also, I've just found here ( https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html ) a list of non round-hour timezones.

Comment: yes, you were right I haven't noticed my time of my system. this silly mistake bugged me a lot. Thank you Sir.