# How to convert CAN message TimeStamp in python Time to System time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-can

```py
import time 
import can

def ReceiveMsg():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel= '1', bustype='vector',app_name = 'python-can')
    while True:
            a_listener = can.Listener()
            Message = bus.recv()
            a_listener.on_message_received(Message)
            if (Message != None) & (Message.arbitration_id == 0x329):
                print('Message is :',Message)
                return Message

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReceiveMsg()
```

if I execute I will get below output

```
Message is : Timestamp: 1559297416.090523        ID: 0329    S                DLC:  8    ca 00 03 28 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
```

`1559297416.090523` - this is Python timestamp

In the output Timestamp: is giving Python time

How can I get Python Time into System Time???

Comment: Does multiplying by 1000 solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694487/in-python-how-do-you-convert-seconds-since-epoch-to-a-datetime-object)

in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.fromtimestamp(Message.timestamp)
```

in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
datetime.fromtimestamp(Message.timestamp, pytz.utc)
```