# timestamp returning different value when calling the function from class

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, blockchain

```
import json
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime
class Block():
    def real_time(self):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(self.timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
        super().__init__()
        self.index = index
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data = data
        self.previous_hash = previous_hash
        self.hash = self.calculate_hash()

# Function to calculate hash values usinf SHA256 algorithm
    def calculate_hash(self):
        string_to_be_hashed = str(
            self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + self.previous_hash + json.dumps(self.data)
        byte_string = string_to_be_hashed.encode()
        return hashlib.sha256(byte_string).hexdigest()


# Instanciating the object of Block class
block = Block(1, 77, "89", "0")
ans = block.calculate_hash()
print(ans)
print(block.real_time())
```

the argument passed in block for timestamp is having value 77 but the output I'm getting when calling real_time method is : **1970-01-01 05:31:17**

Comment: Because you cast `77` seconds as epoch time into a datetime.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694487/in-python-how-do-you-convert-seconds-since-epoch-to-a-datetime-object

Comment: Why is the code that uses `self.timestamp` commented out? Post the code with the problem, not some other code.

Comment: What result are you expecting instead? `tz=None` means to use your local timezone; I guess your timezone is 5.5 hours ahead of UTC.

Comment: I am expecting to get a timestamp when the block get's created @Barmar

Comment: But what timestamp are you expecting when original value is `77`?

Comment: `1970-01-01 05:31:17` is a timestamp, isn't it?

Comment: Yes what I meant is I'm trying to get current time when the block get's created.

Comment: from the datetime module, import `timezone` and use `datetime.fromtimestamp(self.timestamp, tz=timezone.utc)` to get UTC