# Python: UTC vs local timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, timezone, local, utc

Why the followings return different timestamp? Is it because datetime.utcnow() doesn't have a timezone? It looks to me that *tzinfo=utc* is redudant, so I am probably not getting what is *utcnow()* and how an UTC number could not have a timezone. I guess there is a reason, so please enlight me :)

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import utc

local_seconds = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
utc_seconds = int(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc).timestamp())
```

My goal is to get the UTC timestamp. It looks like the first method returns the local timestamp (correct me if I am wrong)

EDIT:
Where I live the timezone is GMT-5. In fact:

```
(utc_seconds-local_seconds)/3600 # is equal to -5.0
```

Comment: could you share the bigger issue?
pytz is a non default library, maybe you can solve your problem in another ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following two statements would always return different result.

```
local_seconds = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
utc_seconds = int(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc).timestamp())
```

Output:

```
1585584790
1585604590
```

You ask why? Because, by the time first statement executes, there is some time spent during execution and now the second statement would fetch you different result because `datetime.utcnow()` for 2nd statement has changed.

What I assume is, you want to see if both operations would give the same result or not? They definitely would have given the same results :

1. Had you provided them the same input?
2. Had you performed the similar operation from a common library.

To solve 1. change your code like this.

```
same_time_input = datetime.utcnow()

local_seconds = int(same_time_input.timestamp())
utc_seconds = int(same_time_input.replace(tzinfo=utc).timestamp())
```

Still the output would not be same, because you are using an external library, and the replace function is not working as you expected.

If you printout the tzinfo from `same_time_input`, you would see that it doesn't have any timezone info reason of which can be read here. --> [Why does datetime.datetime.utcnow() not contain timezone information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331592/why-does-datetime-datetime-utcnow-not-contain-timezone-information)

```
print(same_time_input.tzinfo)
```

Now, you are trying to give it a timezone info using a separate library which has different implementation internally resulting in `slightly off` results.

Comment: Point was exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331592/why-does-datetime-datetime-utcnow-not-contain-timezone-information