# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to set a DateTimeField for one of my django models. My code looks like this:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(parsed_feed.updated_parsed))
feed.updated = dt
```

updated_parsed is struct in the format :

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=26, tm_hour=8, tm_min=20, tm_sec=43, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=117, tm_isdst=0)
```

And updated is obviously the django DateTimeField. I am trying to convert the struct into a datetime object, and then set it to my field. Everything works nicely, and the correct date and time is set, however, I get this error (warning) in my console:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Feed.updated received a naive datetime (2016-04-26 08:25:08) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

How do I integrate timezone support into the datetime object (dt)?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607411/django-runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime-while-time-zon):

The following line creates a naive (non-timezone aware) datetime:

```
creationDate = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Try changing that line to:

```
creationDate = timezone.now()
```

Don't forget to import timezone at the beginning of your code:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the pytz package.
So import pytz into your views.

```
t = pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw').localize(
    datetime(2013, 5, 11, hour=11, minute=0))
```

Your timezone should be set in your settings.py
[datetime and timezone conversion with pytz - mind blowing behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541051/datetime-and-timezone-conversion-with-pytz-mind-blowing-behaviour)