# RunTimeWarning : DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, runtime-error

I am trying to test a cart creation based on [django cart](https://github.com/bmentges/django-cart/blob/master/cart/tests.py). But I have the following warning when I am trying to create the cart:

```
RunTimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support 
is active
```

I did some research but I couldn't resolve my problem for `datetime.datetime.now()`.

test_views.py in my tests directory :

```py
from front.cart import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def create_cart_in_database():
    cart = models.Cart()
    cart.creationDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    cart.save()
```

models.py :

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

I also have `USE_TZ = True` in my settings.

I tried `timezone.now()` but still doesn't work :

```py
def create_cart_in_database():
    creationDate = timezone.now()
```

```
RunTimeWarning: DateTimeField Cart.creationDate received a naive datetime 
(2016-06-03 08:46:34.829000) while time zone support is active.
```

Edit: I have this error now and it seems an error related to datetime format?

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.5-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 1399, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.5-py2.7.egg\django\utils\datepa
rse.py", line 93, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Aside from Selcuk's answer, you might want to avoid setting the methods default to the `now()` method. I'm pretty sure it won't be executed every time you call the function... just when first initialized

Comment: @Sayse So do you any idea about how I can give another date instead of now() ?

Comment: `now` is correct (and I suspect you may still be running the old code and may need to restart the dev server). Simpy set the default to `None` and then check inside the method if it is none and if so set it to now inside of it

Comment: @Sayse I restarted the server but nothing changed. I am so sorry but could I ask you where and how I set the default to None ? I am still a newbie ...

Comment: `def _create_cart_in_database(self, creationDate=None..`

Comment: @Sayse I set the default to None but he continues to give me the same error with actual datetime ...

Comment: William P, that wouldn't stop this error, it would stop a different one from occuring. You should try to create a [mcve], the given duplicate and Selcuks answer should solve the problem.

Comment: this is curious. can you try "models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)" and let us know what happens

Comment: @AdityaPandhare I tried your solution and I edited my post where you can find the new error

Comment: if you can, clear up your migrations and try it once more. refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220480/django-datetime-migration-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The following line creates a naive (non-timezone aware) datetime:

```
creationDate = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Try changing that line to:

```
creationDate = timezone.now()
```

Don't forget to import `timezone` at the beginning of your code:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/958e4cfe42190539af9386e753d59cd487bd8847/django/utils/timezone.py#L200-L204), `django.utilts.timezone.now` is precisely `datetime.datetime.now` only with the timezone set to UTC. So if you want to make it work with `datetime`, then use the following:

```py
import datetime
creationDate = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If you got the warning when setting a specific datetime (not `now`), then pass the `tzinfo` using whatever timezone it should be. If it's UTC it's pretty straightforward, just pass `datetime.timezone.utc`.

```py
creationDate = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 7, 11, 31)  # <--- RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime ...

creationDate = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 7, 11, 31, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)  # <--- no warning
```

If the datetime should be in specific timezone, then since Python 3.9, `zoneinfo` module, which provides implementation to support the IANA time zone database, is in the standard library. So for example, if the timezone should be Tokyo (or UTC+09:00), then one could use the following.

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
creationDate = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 7, 11, 31, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Asia/Tokyo"))
```

---

On the other hand, if you got

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

or

```py
fromisoformat: argument must be str
```

see if you forgot to call the function e.g. `timezone.now()`/`datetime.datetime.now()` and instead passed the function itself e.g. `timezone.now`.