# Maintain timezone awareness with date and time arithmetic

Tags: python, django, datetime

According to [Django : RunTimeWarning : DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607411/django-runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime-while-time-zon), get today's date with timezone information with

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now()
```

When I do:

```
from datetime import timedelta
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
```

But now `yesterday` is no longer timezone aware. How do I maintain the timezone awareness while doing date and time arithmetic?

Comment: Which version of django you running this on? I tried with 1.11 it seems fine. Can you check both var for tzinfo attribute?

Comment: @DuD. I am using 1.11.3.

Comment: Make sure USE_TZ = True in your setting

Comment: @DuD. That is set. As I understand it, this is the cause of the warning.